# find the limit of $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}} $

Tags: limits, functions, logarithms, limits-without-lhopital

How can I find the limit : $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$

I know I can use the following statement:

$$(1+x)^{1/x}=e^{\frac 1 x\log(1+x)}$$

but I don't know how to continue from there

(I'm still not allowed to use Lhoptial if that could be used here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \exp\left( \frac{\log(1+x)}{x}\right)= \exp\left( \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}\right).
\end{align}
Since
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\log(1+x)}{x} = 0
\end{align}
then it follows
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \exp\left( \frac{\log(1+x)}{x}\right)=1
\end{align}

Note
\begin{align}
\log(1+x) \leq \sqrt{x}
\end{align}
when $x>0$.

**Additional:**

The definition of $\log(1+x)$ is defined to be
\begin{align}
\log(1+x) := \int^x_0 \frac{dt}{1+t}
\end{align}
and since
\begin{align}
\sqrt{x} = \int^x_0 \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}}
\end{align}
then we have
\begin{align}
\sqrt{x}-\log(1+x) = \int^x_0 \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}-\frac{1}{t+1}\ dt\geq 0
\end{align}
since
\begin{align}
1+t\geq \sqrt{t} \ \ \Leftrightarrow 1-\sqrt{t}+t = \frac{3}{4}+\left(\sqrt{t}-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\geq 0.
\end{align}

Comment: How would you prove that $\lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{\log(1+x)}{x}=0$?

Comment: @flytothesurface I hope my post have answered your question.

Comment: Thank you. Actually it does, but I still don't know a way of proving that inequality without involving derivatives

Answer (score 0):

$$A=\lim_{x \to \infty} (1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}\\ \ln A=\ln \lim_{x \to \infty} (1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}\\=
\lim_{x \to \infty} \ln (1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}=\\
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x}\ln(1+x)=\\
 \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=\\
 \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{1+x}}{1}=0\\
\ln A=0 \to A=e^0=1 $$

Comment: Could you explain why : $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=
 \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{1+x}}{1}$

Comment: I used hop rule , and $$(\ln(f(x))'=\frac{f'}{f} \to (\ln(1+x))'=\frac{1}{1+x}$$